# 104, Connection reset by peer. When sending multiple long http post requests

Tags: python, http, tcp, python-requests, tornado

I have a kubernetes cluster (on GKE) which runs tornado.web.Application server, that calls heavy dask.distributed calculations on that cluster.
Now I want to test my server, and send it multiple requests at once, to see if it handles those requests as it should.
When I'm sending only one request, it does everything and behaves as expected, no matter how big the request is.
But when I send more than one request, after like 5 minutes (I also tried on server side just to sleep, without making any calculations and got the same results), I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1354, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 306, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 267, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 756, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 531, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 706, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 445, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 440, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1354, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 306, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 267, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 589, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-4-ce4ad22684d3>", line 24, in fire
    response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, timeout=3600)
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 119, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

And none of the requests returns.

How can I get the behaviour I need, without these errors?
I need a server that can handle many requests, and to test it from my computer.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *"sending only one request"* vs. *"send more than one request"*? Sending these multiple requests one after the other over the same TCP connection (HTTP keep-alive)? Multiple TCP connections same time (parallel connections)? Single TCP connection multiple request after each other but without waiting for the responses (HTTP pipelining)? Or did you somehow handcraft requests and these might simply not be proper HTTP requests at all?

Comment: Thanks @SteffenUllrich,
I'm just using python request.post many times parallely, I think it uses multiple connections.
Should I change this usage?
Thanks

Comment: And *"when I send more than one request,"* also includes just sending two requests? Or how many requests you actually send in parallel?

Comment: Well I tried three, but I think that it will be the same also for 2 requests, I'm checking now, it usually takes 5 minutes to crash.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich it's being reproduced also with two requests

Comment: Might be a bug in your server then - or maybe intended behavior that it explicitly limits the resources a single client can access. There is likely nothing you can do from the client side - the server (or something in between) simply closes the connection. Thus, look outside the client, maybe be simplifying the setup (like running outside of kubernetes).